# Is there a way to update the colour of these canvases?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
row1a = Canvas(firstFrame,width=54,height=54,bg="gray")
row1a.pack(side=LEFT)
row1b = Canvas(firstFrame,width=54,height=54,bg="gray40")
row1b.pack(side=LEFT)
row1c = Canvas(firstFrame,width=54,height=54,bg="gray")
row1c.pack(side=LEFT)
row1d = Canvas(firstFrame,width=54,height=54,bg="gray40")
row1d.pack(side=LEFT)
row1e = Canvas(firstFrame,width=54,height=54,bg="gray")
row1e.pack(side=LEFT)
row1f = Canvas(firstFrame,width=54,height=54,bg="gray40")
row1f.pack(side=LEFT)
row1g = Canvas(firstFrame,width=54,height=54,bg="gray")
row1g.pack(side=LEFT)

row = 1
column = b
```

Is there a way i can update the "row1b" canvas' colour using something like canvas.config(bg="blue").
There are a lot more of these canvases so I cant really use row1b.config(bg="blue") for each canvas.
Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? If you save the canvases in a list rather than a bunch of disjoint variables, it would be trivial.

Comment: how could I save canvases in a list?

Answer (score 0):

Like with any widget, you can change its options after it's been created.

Since you are creating many canvases, the best solution is to store them in a list or dictionary. Since you seem to want to reference them with numbers and letters, a dictionary might be the best solution.

For example, to create the canvas objects in a loop you could do something like this:

```
canvases = {}
row = 1
for column in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'):
    index = (row, column)
    canvases[index] = Canvas(...)
```

Later, you can change the color of any single canvas via the `canvases` dictionary and the `configure` command:

```
canvases[(1,'c')].configure(background="blue")
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ill do it that way instead!